# How does template in django get the user object?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

How does template get user object?

In other words what process exactly during rendering passes user object to template?

And what else is accessible in template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Using the [`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) context processor, you can access the `auth.User` instance in your template.**

> If `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` contains this processor, every
>   `RequestContext` will contain these variables:
>
> **`user`** – An `auth.User` instance representing the currently logged-in user
>   (or an AnonymousUser instance, if the client isn’t logged in).

Just define `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` in your  `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` settings and then use `{{user}}` in your template.

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth", # define this in your settings
....
)
```

**Template Context Processors:**

> Its a tuple of callables that are **used to populate the context** in
>   RequestContext. These callables take a request object as their
>   argument and return a dictionary of items to be merged into the
>   context.

By default the following context processors are set by Django 1.6.

```
("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")
```

**What variables are present in the template?**

You can know which all variables are present in all the template by the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` settings. Each context processor defined in it includes some variables into the context. For example, [`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) includes a `user` variable containing the `user` object, [`django.core.context_processors.media`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-media) context processor includes `MEDIA_URL` variable in the template.

To check what all variables are accessible in a template using different context processors, refer this [Django documentation link.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)

**Accessing the `request` object in the context**

You can add [`django.core.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in `settings.py` and access the `request` object in your context.

You can also access the current user as `{{ request.user }}`. You will have to explicitly add this setting as it is not present by default.

Add `.request` context processor to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your settings.

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ....
    `django.core.context_processors.request`,
    )
```

**EDIT: (Thanks [@Ozgur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793428/ozgur))**

Also, add the [`AUTHENTICATION_MIDDLEWARE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/middleware/#module-django.contrib.auth.middleware) in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` settings for `user` attribute to be set in the `request` object. It was removed from the default `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` settings in [Django 1.7.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#middleware-classes)

> class AuthenticationMiddleware
>   Adds the `user` attribute, representing the currently-logged-in user, to every incoming `HttpRequest` object.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    # explicitly add the 'AuthenticationMiddleware' class
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: Moreover, one should add [`AuthenticationMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware) in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting to tie current user into requests. Django provides a great [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests) about that.