# Passing variables into extends template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

I have a template named `base.html`. As the name suggests, it is where the header and footer reside. In between these 2 elements, is a `{% block content %}` where the child template can extend this template and add content inside block content.

However, inside header I want the user's name to be shown. For example, `{{ user.username }}` but Django can't seem to recognize this when I extend this template to a child template. Is there a way I can pass in objects to the extends template? That way the logged in user's name is shown?

This is a rough example of what I'm trying to do. user.username does not show even when the user is logged in.

**base.html**

```
<header>
  <h1>Hello, {{ user.username }}</h1>
</header>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
<footer>
 ///Some content
</footer>
```

**child.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
 //Some content
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py for child.html**

```
ChildView(TemplateView):
  template_name = 'child.html'
```

Answer (score 2):

In your child template add this to the top

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

This will allow you to "inherit" the context variable.

Alternatively, if you only want to pass say just the `user` data to the template, you could do the following in your `base.html`

```
{% include 'header.html' with my_user=user %}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863695/include-vs-extends-in-django-templates) answer summarises the differences between `extend` and `include` functionality quite well.

---

**Edit**:

In response to your comments and updated question, you aren't accessing the `user` object correctly. To do so you must use `{{ request.user }}`. This is because [there is a context processor that passes the `user` object to every template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896103/how-does-template-in-django-get-the-user-object).

As an aside, if you were to explicitly send the `user` from the view, you could then access the user with `{{ user }}` as you have done. However, this is obviously quite unnecessary.

Comment: But I want to show the user's username in base.html. How do I do that? The child template doesn't have anything to do with the User model, only the base.html

Comment: @user2896120, add your code to the original post so i can better understand

Comment: Hmm, just so I have this down correctly, what if we want to display something in the header that is from a model (not User, but something like Post where we get the post title with the most views) where would we make this query in order for it to display in base.html so that all pages that extend base.html have the post title with the most views?

Comment: as implied in my answer, the `request` object as well as a couple of other core django objects are passed via context processors - you don't need to explicitly call them to access them in templates. if it is something that is custom to your django application, you need to pass it in your view. e.g. `best_post = get_best_post()`

Comment: So everytime I have a new view, I have to make the query and pass it to the view so base.html can use it if it's custom to my Django application?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the content in `blocks` in child templates are overriden.

**base.html**

```
{% block my_block %}
This content is overriden by child templates
{% endblock my_block %}
```

**child.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block my_block %}
This content is shown
{% endblock my_block %}
```

If you want some content shown in all templates, you shouldn't put inside a block content, but directly in your base template.

**base.html**

```
{{ user.username }}
{% block my_block %}
This content is overriden by child templates
{% endblock my_block %}
```

So, it all comes down to how the layout of your page is done. If the header is always the same, you should not use the block tag.

If it's almost the same, but changes in details, use blocks to change the details:

**header**:

```
<h1>This doesn't change ever 
    {% block this_changes %}
     the child themplate will provide the content
    {% endblock this_changes %}</h1>

   <b>User: {{ user.username }}</b>
```

Comment: I can't get user.username to be shown in base.html though